# angularjs error in state function used in edit module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

method passing in this result

```
$scope.editdst = function(editdstId) {
    http.get("index.php/Welcome/district_edit?id=" + editdstId)
      .then(function(response,result){
        alert(response);
        $scope.row = response.data;
    })   

    $state.go('editdst');
      // $state.go('editdst',{editdstId});

}
```

IN USED FOR STATE METHOD

```
.state('editdst', {
        url: '/editdst?e_Id',
        templateUrl: 'index.php/Welcome/add',

        data: {

          pageTitle: 'Edit District'
        },
         controller:'dstmyctrl',
           params: {
              b: {}
         }


   })
```

But it is not working.

Comment: what is the err?

Comment: i want to going edit page but how can i fetch row  query in angularjs and state.go function url passing